# c++ call an overriden virtual function with a derived argument

Tags: c++

How can I call an overridden virtual function with a derived argument?

The argument I'm calling it with is of a derived class of the argument it was defined and overriden with.

```
//Args
struct ArgBase{
    int val;
};

struct ArgDerived: ArgBase{
    int derivedVal;
};


/////

struct Base {
    int name;
    virtual int doSomething(ArgBase a) = 0;
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    int doSomething(ArgBase a){ //I want to overide Base's virtual function, so I need to pass in an ArgBase here (and not an ArgDerived)
        
        return a.derviedVal; //<------------- how can I get this to work?
        // option 1: return static_cast<ArgDerived>(a).derviedVal; does not work
        // option 2: can I may be do something like "if(a is ArgDerived){....}"?
    }
};

int main ()
{
  Derived d;//object of derived class

  ArgDerived ad; //object of derived argument class
  ad.val = 25;
  ad.derivedVal = 75;
  
  std::cout << d.doSomething(ad) << std::endl; //<---------- call with derived argument ad
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No amount of runtime type checking is going to help if `doSomething` accepts an `ArgBase` by value, because even if you pass it an `ArgDerived` it'll be sliced. You may be able to achieve what you're looking for by making `a` an `ArgBase&` or `const ArgBase&` reference, and then making whatever features you care about accessible via virtual functions presented in the `ArgBase` interface. But without knowing what this is actually supposed to accomplish in what kind of context it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should accept the argument by reference or pointer for it to behave polymorphically

```
virtual int doSomething(const ArgBase& a) = 0;
```

then you can cast in your overriden function

```
return static_cast<const ArgDerived&>(a).derviedVal;
```

of course `static_cast` assumes that this cast is valid at runtime. If you are unsure of the derived type being passed then you'd need to use something like `dynamic_cast` which will throw a `std::bad_cast` if the reference is not of that type. Or use some other pattern, but the point being you must only `static_cast` if that type is appropriate at runtime.

Comment: With the caveat that this will result in undefined behavior if someone calls `Derived::doSomething` with something that can't be converted to `ArgDerived`, of course.

Comment: thats what preconditions are for.
But you are right. this would violate against the substitution principle

Comment: I added some more details about the cast behavior/safety to address this